# Await dispatch to do fetch, REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api

I have some problem, i modify an object with dispatch and do a fetch at the same time, sending the old object (i want send the new object modified), here i show my code:

```
if (personaModified) {
          editEmpresaById({ id: +id, data: empresa });
        } else {
          dispatch(empresaPersonaSetNull(null));
          editEmpresaById({ id: +id, data: empresa });
        }
```

empresaPersonaSetNull modified the empresa object, put empresa.persona null.

I want, if personaModified is false, modifie empresa with dispatch and seend to API the new object, but i send at the same time this dispatch and editEmpresaById, and is seending the old empresa object,

editEmpresaById code:

```
 const editEmpresaById = async ({ id, data }: EditEmpresaParams) => {
    try {
      dispatch(loadingSet(true));
      const response = await empresaApi.put<EmpresaDTO>(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/edit/${id}`, data);
      dispatch(loadingSet(false));
      dispatch(empresaSet(response.data));
    } catch ({ response: { status } }) {
      getToastError(status);
    }
  };
```

empresaPersonaSetNull code (is a slice):

```
empresaPersonaSetNull: (state: EmpresaState, action: PayloadAction<null>) => {
   state.empresa.persona = action.payload;
},
```

Please, can any help me? thanks :D

I need send the new objet empresa to API, but don't have time to update the new object and send this.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the state and the API request at the same time instead you have to update the state after the API request has been completed successfully. You can do this by moving the `dispatch` call inside the `then` block of the `Promise` returned by the API request

Your if-else block should look like this

```
if (personaModified) {
  editEmpresaById({ id: +id, data: empresa });
} else {
  dispatch(empresaPersonaSetNull(null));
  editEmpresaById({ id: +id, data: empresa }).then(() => {
    dispatch(empresaSet(empresa));
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need backend take the new value, this code only set at my store the new object empresa, but back get the old value. I need the dispatch set the new value and after send the api.

this is the empresaSet code (its a slice too):

```
empresaSet: (state: EmpresaState, action: PayloadAction<EmpresaDTO>) => {
      state.empresa = action.payload;
      state.immutableModel = action.payload;
},
```